# Wordpress - Is there a way to restrict registration only for certain users?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am setting up a Wordpress page for a customer. The website's purpose is to be a photo contest for his employees.

The one and only problem I have is the requirement that registration on the website has to be closed only for users who work in the company. Which means, their workID will match the one from a list I will receive.

Is that possible?

Comment: Ofc it is. I would suggest making another table with workID and have on registration page input for ID. Then in php check if `workID in ( SELECT workID from 'tableName' )` . But pay attention to your CONSTRAINTS because you do not want 2 users with same workID.

Comment: What are you referring to by “workID”, is that some sort of custom field you added to the user objects in your system? Or how else is that connected to the user registration process?

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://www.cssigniter.com/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-the-wordpress-registration-form/) is the tutorial using which you will be able to customize registration form and will figure out how to validate form data.

After learning tutorial all you have to do is following:

- Save those `workID`s in your DB
- Add new registration form field named `workID`
- Add new logic to form registration controller where you should check for existing of user provided `workID`

Don't forget to mark used `workID`s and link them to user accounts.